# Error.java.sql.SQLException:No value specified for parameter 7

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Necesito ayuda para poder modificar la tabla de MySQL con un *FRM*

```
Pool metodospool = new Pool();    

public void Modificar(String id,String nombre, String categoria, String codigo,String precio, 
                      String marca){

int confirmar = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea modificar los datos actuales?");

if(confirmar == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){

    Connection conexion = null;

    try {

        conexion = metodospool.dataSource.getConnection();

        String Ssql = "UPDATE productos SET  (id,nombre,categoria,codigo,precio,marca) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) WHERE id=?";
        //problemas en esta parte 
        PreparedStatement prest = conexion.prepareStatement(Ssql);
        prest.setString(1, id);
        prest.setString(2, nombre);
        prest.setString(3, categoria);
        prest.setString(4, codigo);
        prest.setString(5, precio);
        prest.setString(6, marca);



        if(prest.executeUpdate() > 0){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los datos han sido modificados con éxito", "Operación Exitosa", 
                                          JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }else{

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido realizar la actualización de los datos\n"
                                          + "Inténtelo nuevamente.", "Error en la operación", 
                                          JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {//error al modificar base de datos una tabla el error es aqui

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido realizar la actualización de los datos\n"
                                          + "Inténtelo nuevamente.\n"
                                          + "Error: "+e, "Error en la operación", 
                                          JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }finally{

        if(conexion!=null){

            try {

                conexion.close();

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar cerrar la conexión."
                                          + "Error: "+e, "Error en la operación", 
                                          JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }

        }

    }


}


//error al modificar base de datos una tabla
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El mensaje de error dice que te falta el parámetro `7` que sería el `id` del `WHERE`, aunque es raro modificar el `id` en una consulta UPDATE, ten cuidado, sobre todo si esa columna es la llave primaria.

Además tu consulta tiene la sintaxis habitual de `INSERT`.

Quizá deberías escribir tu consulta así, más bien:

```
    /*Un marcador menos porque no actualizaremos el id*/
    String Ssql = "UPDATE productos SET nombre=?, categoria=?, codigo=?, precio=?, marca=? WHERE id=?";
    //problemas en esta parte 
    PreparedStatement prest = conexion.prepareStatement(Ssql);
    /*El parámetro 1 es el nombre y así sucesivamente*/
    prest.setString(1, nombre);
    prest.setString(2, categoria);
    prest.setString(3, codigo);
    prest.setString(4, precio);
    prest.setString(5, marca);
    /*Asegúrate que la columna id no es numérica, en ese caso debes usar setInt*/
    prest.setString(6, id);
```

Si **por algún motivo justificado debes modifcar el `id`**, entonces el código quedaría así:

```
    String Ssql = "UPDATE productos SET id=?, nombre=?, categoria=?, codigo=?, precio=?, marca=? WHERE id=?";
    //problemas en esta parte 
    PreparedStatement prest = conexion.prepareStatement(Ssql);
    prest.setString(1, id);
    prest.setString(2, nombre);
    prest.setString(3, categoria);
    prest.setString(4, codigo);
    prest.setString(5, precio);
    prest.setString(6, marca);
    //Esto faltaba, hay que poner un dato por cada marcador ?
    prest.setString(7, id);
```

Comment: muchas gracias si me olvide de colocar el id al final no estoy modificando el id solo lo muestro pero no es editable gracias por el codigo de ayuda no me di cuenta del id al final, me dio curiosidad en algo boto error por syntaxis utilice esta no se porque:String Ssql = "UPDATE productos SET  nombre=?,categoria=?,codigo=?,precio=?,marca=? WHERE id=?"; GRACIAS

Comment: @SaidMartos claro, no me di cuenta que tu consulta tenía el estilo que se usa para consultas del tipo `INSERT`. En las consultas `UPDATE` se suele usar `SET`(aunque algunos manejadores permiten un estilo parecido al `INSERT` es bueno escribir las consultas según el estándar). He corregido ese aspecto en la respuesta.

Comment: de nuevo muchísimas Gracias