# ¿Como hago que funcione mi funcion update?

Tags: java

Este es mi codigo de conexion que utilizo para conectarme a la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es mi sentencia no entiendo porque me falla el update

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Nosotros tampoco, porque ver codigo en imagenes es muy pero muy dificil.. de paso.. que error sale?? como termina siendo tu sql? es correcto si lo probas en la db?

Comment: Atiende los comentarios que te hacen, ve a [edit] y mejora tu pregunta, por favor

Comment: Amigo, te aconsejo que copies y pegue tu codigo en lugar de un pantallazo, porque ademas de que se hace superdificil leer el codigo, es mucho mas complicado ayudarte en base a tu codigo

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error.java.sql.SQLException:No value specified for parameter 7](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/314685/error-java-sql-sqlexceptionno-value-specified-for-parameter-7). Tienes serios problemas de sintaxis en el código, así como de seguridad. La mejor forma de resolver esto es corrigiendo la sintaxis y usando consultas preparadas, como muestra la respuesta aceptada en esa pregunta.